# How to create and share navGraph scopped ViewModel instance to navigate between UI states in Jetpack Compose in Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have the below navigation graph with Jetpack Compose:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.authGraph(navController: NavController) {
    navigation(startDestination = "login", route = "auth") {
        composable("login") {
            val authEntry = remember(it) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry("auth")
            }

            val vm: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(authEntry)
            LoginScreen(vm)
        }
        composable("register") {
            val authEntry = remember(it) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry("auth")
            }

            val vm: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(authEntry)
            RegisterScreen(vm)
        }
        composable("confirm") {
            val authEntry = remember(it) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry("auth")
            }

            val vm: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(authEntry)
            ConfirmRegisterScreen(vm)
        }
    }
}
```

The `AuthViewModel` has the below UI state which I update as the user progress from sign up to confirm sign up and its workflows

```
sealed class AuthUiState {
    object SignedOut : AuthUiState()
    object InProgress : AuthUiState()
    object SignIn : AuthUiState()
    object SignedIn: AuthUiState()
    object ConfirmSignIn: AuthUiState()
    object ConfirmSignUp: AuthUiState()
    object Registered: AuthUiState()
} 

private val _uiState = mutableStateOf<AuthUiState>(SignedOut)
val uiState: State<AuthUiState> get() = _uiState
```

I wanted to observe this `uiState` state change inside the AuthGraph and navigate to the appropriate destination. How do I find the `AuthViewModel` instance outside of the composable?

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.authGraph(navController: NavController) {
    val vm: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(`common viewmodelstore object`)
    when (vm.uiState) {
        .... navController.navigate("login")
        .... navController.navigate("register")
    }

    navigation(startDestination = "login", route = "auth") {
        composable("login") {
            val authEntry = remember(it) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry("auth")
            }

            val vm: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(authEntry)
            LoginScreen(vm)
        }

        ..... other auth flow routes
    }
}
```

I do know that there is a back stack entry which can be used to obtain the same viewmodel instance within the composibles for the nested graphs as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav). However, what viewmodel store key can I use to obtain the viewmodel instance outside of the composible route to navigate between the nested routes with the Hilt DI? `hiltViewModel()` is a composable function which only works inside the `composible` route function.

Comment: found solution?

Comment: @ArunNS I ended up using activity scoped ViewModel for authentication module composable. compose navigation doesn't provide any APIs to access viewmodels scoped out of navgraph outside of the navgraph composables. Which does make sense, but still a question how one would implement a common navigation between auth screens based on viewmodel state change.